# How to complete a new friend quest?

Tags: starbound

I have a simple quest, build a house with a neighbor for my tenant, house should have:

- 1 colony deed
- 1 torch
- 1 wooden table
- 1 wooden door

Seems easy but no matter what I build, it does not work. I have a tenant living there, so it is considered a house, but quest won't complete...

[image]

[image]

P.S. Another guy asks a house with 3 pieces of technology. Placed a fridge oven and a fan, but that won't cut it. Don't know which technology he wants...

Comment: Try to put all the 4 itens in the same "rectangle", By saying that I mean blocking with walls that right side of the building instead of having a door.

Comment: I tried that, then it becomes a non-house at all for some reason...

Comment: The only difference I noticed from people that got their houses working was having a taller room, not only 3 blocks high.

Comment: Did your quest specify a race for the new colonist? The last two 'build a home' quests I got did, and the game only marked the quest as complete when I managed to get a tenant of the race in.

Answer (score 2):

I just had this happen to me.  I believe for the quest to complete, the colony deed must be the last item placed.  Try using the matter manipulator to remove the deed to clear the current tenant and then replace it.